# Substring Comparison in python

Tags: python

If i have List PhoneDirectory
Eg:

```
['John:009878788677' , 'Jefrey:67654654645' , 'Maria:8787677766']
```

Which is the function that can be use to compare the Presence of Substring (Eg: Joh) in each entry in the List .

I have tried using

```
if(PhoneDirectory.find(Joh) != -1)
```

but it doesnt work

kindly Help..

Comment: Your naming is little of. Capital letter variable names are usually reserved by convention to Classes. PhoneDirectory looks list of strings for me, I would call it phonenumbers according to Python naming conventions. I find it usefull to have list variable names to be plural.

Comment: Just to point out, would this not be best stored as a dictionary?
`{ s.split( ":" )[ 0 ]: s.split( ":" )[ 1 ] for s in ... }`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to check each entry separately:

```
for entry in PhoneDirectory:
    if 'John' in entry: ...
```

If you just want to know if *any* entry satisfies the condition and don't care which one:

```
if any('John' in entry for entry in PhoneDirectory):
    ...
```

Note that `any` will do no "wasted" work -- it will return `True` as soon as it finds any *one* entry meeting the condition (if no entries meet the condition, it does have to check every single one of them to confirm that, of course, and then returns `False`).

Comment: As you are close to development of Python, do you know why any does not return the first "True" value (say "Johnny") but only less useful True (even the interpreter must know the exact answer). That is: to work like or in Python or "useful result" principle in Lisp? BTW maybe it should be:
if any(entry.startswith'John:' in entry for entry in PhoneDirectory)

Comment: @Tony, since `any` has to return `False` (e.g. for an empty list, can't just "return some false value from the sequence") when it says "no", for symmetry reason it was judged better to always make it return a boolean. Re your BTW, perhaps, but (if so) then only after fixing the syntax error in your suggestion (put parentheses around `'John:'`;-).

Comment: I have not your godly powers to change it any more. Should always run the code before sending out ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
if any(entry.startswith('John:') in entry for entry in PhoneDirectory)
```

But I would prepare something with two elements as you list of strings is not well suited to task:

```
PhoneList = ['John:009878788677' , 'Jefrey:67654654645' , 'Maria:8787677766']

numbers = { a:b 
            for item in PhoneList
            for a,_,b in (item.partition(':'),)
            }

print numbers
print "%s's number is %s." % ( 'John', numbers['John'] )
```

Answer (score 1):

Since no one has recommended this yet, I would do:

```
all_johns = [p for p in PhoneDirectory if 'Joh' in p]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a split on ":" and look for occurrences of what you are looking for in the first element of the resulting array.

```
dir = ['John:009878788677' , 'Jefrey:67654654645' , 'Maria:8787677766'];
for a in dir:
    values = a.split(":")
    if values[0] == "John":
        print("John's number is %s" % (values[1]))
```

Comment: A bit overly complicated, there's really no need to split each entry.

Comment: True. This is the only way I know how to do that in Python! :-) Loved the "any" answer.

Answer (score 0):

If performance counts for this task use some [SuffixTree](http://hkn.eecs.berkeley.edu/~dyoo/python/suffix_trees/) implementation. Or just make any DBMS engine do the indexing job.